# Representing List at root of output in AWS Smithy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to use AWS Smithy to describe a service that returns a list of objects. I can only find examples where the output is a structure (e.g., having a `page` and an `items` member). However, the API I want to wrap returns a JSON list at the root of the output.

```
$ curl https://server/endpoint
[...]
[{"obj": 1}, {"obj": 2}]
```

How can I represent this in AWS Smithy?

Comment: Hm, by [this](https://smithy.io/1.0/spec/core/model.html?highlight=list#operation) it looks like such endpoints are not supported by smithy 1.0: "The input of the operation defined using a shape ID that MUST target a structure." And [this](https://smithy.io/2.0/spec/type-refinement-traits.html#smithy-api-output-trait) appears to indicate that it is unsupported by smithy 2.0: "Summary /     Specializes a structure for use only as the output of a single operation."